# in htaccess RewriteEngine not work on specific directory

Tags: .htaccess, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I using `yii2` and I have a problem in `.htaccess` as below:

I can't access to `js` directory to use including files in my code.

ex: `yii2/sepadmin/js/jquery.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

Here is my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

# deal with sepadmin first
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/yii2/(sepadmin)
RewriteRule ^sepadmin/assets/(.*)$ backend/web/assets/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^sepadmin/css/(.*)$ backend/web/css/$1 [L] #Accessible
RewriteRule ^sepadmin/js/(.*)$ backend/web/js/$1 [L] # Not Accessible

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/yii2/backend/web/(assets|css)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/yii2/(sepadmin)
RewriteRule ^.*$ backend/web/index.php [L]
```

As I mentioned the line, I can access `css` directory but I can't access `js` directory

Comment: Could this be a caching issue? Have a try with an anonymous browser tab.

Comment: @arkascha yes I have tried it, but still its problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I had to use directory name in `REQUEST_URI` as bellow.

```
RewriteEngine On

# deal with sepadmin first
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/yii2/(sepadmin)
RewriteRule ^sepadmin/assets/(.*)$ backend/web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^sepadmin/css/(.*)$ backend/web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^sepadmin/js/(.*)$ backend/web/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^sepadmin/files/(.*)$ backend/web/files/$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/yii2/backend/web/(assets|css|js|files)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/yii2/(sepadmin)
RewriteRule ^.*$ backend/web/index.php [L]
```